# Intellij + Ajc + Lombok/Mapstruct

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, mapstruct, intellij-lombok-plugin

I want to enable AspectJ compiler in my IntelliJ Idea as I have several aspects that I'd like to be woven during compile time.

At the same time, I am using Lombok and Mapstruct in my codebase.

Those 2 require additional annotations processing, that must happen before `ajc` kicks in. 
I have both plugins installed for Lombok and Mapstruct. Independently they work fine, source code is being generated. But when I enable `ajc` and tick `Enable annotation processing options`, and then build a project, I get:

```
Error:(9, 0) ajc: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.NullPointerException   at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.FieldBinding.sourceField(FieldBinding.java:425)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl$SourceLocationComparator.determineSourceStart(TypeElementImpl.java:108)      at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl$SourceLocationComparator.getSourceStart(TypeElementImpl.java:72)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl$SourceLocationComparator.compare(TypeElementImpl.java:65)    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl$SourceLocationComparator.compare(TypeElementImpl.java:1)     at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:360)     at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)     at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)      at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462)    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeElementImpl.getEnclosedElements(TypeElementImpl.java:166)    at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.workarounds.SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.replaceTypeElementIfNecessary(SpecificCompilerWorkarounds.java:99)    at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.Executables.getAllEnclosedExecutableElements(Executables.java:99)     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getAllMethods(Type.java:633)     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.common.Type.getPropertyReadAccessors(Type.java:496)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.build(BeanMappingMethod.java:168)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreationProcessor.java:376)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreationProcessor.java:151)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:122)    at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:76)     at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:283)     at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:263)    at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:221)   at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:156)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:139)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:121)   at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:931)     at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)    at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)    at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1036)   at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:272)      at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:185)    at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.build.AjJpsCompiler.doBuild(AjJpsCompiler.java:249)    at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.build.AjJpsCompiler.build(AjJpsCompiler.java:119)      at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.build.AjTranslatingBuilder.doBuild(AjTranslatingBuilder.java:114)      at com.intellij.lang.aspectj.build.AjBuilderBase.build(AjBuilderBase.java:74)   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1328)      at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1008)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1075)   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:969)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:798)      at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:380)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:139)     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:302)   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:135)    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:228)   at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, I see a bunch of other `ajc` compilation errors as it is not able to locate methods that should've been generated by the Lombok.

How do I solve these issues?

Comment: Which version of acj are you using? Do you have the same problem with your build tool?

Comment: ```/aspectj/aspectjtools/1.8.13/aspectjtools-1.8.13.jar```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enabling `Post-compile weave mode` in IntelliJ solved it for me (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-the-aspectj-ajc-compiler.html).

Answer (score 5):

Hi I had similar issue.

The fix was to let aspectj-maven-plugin to only start weaving after classes are compiled.

It describes in more detail here https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveDirectories.html

I needed to:

(1) Specify folder where already compiled classes will be via `<weaveDirectories >`

(2) Change the phase of maven-compiler-plugin lifecycle to be run "process-classes" or later.

This is how my pom looked like.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel="spring"</compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy=ERROR</compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true</compilerArg>
                    <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorVersionInfoComment=true</compilerArg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>${showWeaveInfo}</showWeaveInfo>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>${java.compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>false</verbose>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                <sources/>
                <weaveDirectories>
                    <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                </weaveDirectories>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.lib.test</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.lib.test2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: For some reason, tests are not being properly compiled with the setup that you provided.

`[ERROR] The method getAList() is undefined for the type TransactionalIT.ObjectGraph
 ...transactional/NestedTransactionsJdbcDao.java:26
createEntitiesA(og.getAList());`

Comment: any idea what part is the culprit here?

Comment: Here is the error that I see: `Error:(18, 0) ajc: No property named "contentType" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "createdTime"?` This is caused by lombok processor not being invoked. I had tried it to configure but no luck.

Comment: Here is the warning that precedes that error: `Warning:ajc: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BatchProcessingEnvImpl
Lombok supports: sun/apple javac 1.6, ECJ`

Comment: I think that it would make sense to publish an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub in order to enable us to reproduce and analyse your problem.

Comment: Good example with 3 annotation processors: lombok, mapstruct and aspectj. I followed the indications here, that compile information from aspectj plugin and other similar issues, and it works. The key here is let aspectj weave generated classes and not interfere with mapstruct and aspectj processors for code generation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have aspect sources with the same project then you should add a few line codes to the @jun-huh answers and delete `<aspectLibraries>`. The below `pom.xml` is for if you use your aspects with the same project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>az.sanco</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.14.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <proc>none</proc><!-- annotation process already finished, so we don't need to run again-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-only-aspect-files</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--when `javac` compile works it does not copy *.aj files to the 
                            output directory. We need to run `ajc` compile during `compile` phase and 
                            copy only *.aj files to weave our classes-->
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.aj</include><!--IMPORTANT-->
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```